# Avoid "The SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection" exception when use retryPolicy with SqlAzureExecutionStrategy

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure-sql-server

I've read various questions/suggestions about this exception. However what I am supposed to do in order to avoid it when I use retry policy? Connection might not end up closed and so parameters could not be reused?

```
public class ReliableSqlCommand
{     
     public List<ResultType> ExecuteReader<ResultType>() where ResultType : new()
            {
                var list = new List<ResultType>();
                var retryPolicy = new DWSqlAzureExecutionStrategy(SqlMaxRetryCount, SqlMaxDelay);
                retryPolicy.Execute(() =>
                {
                    list = new List<ResultType>();
                    using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
                    {
                        using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(CommandText, sqlConnection))
                        {
                            sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = CommandTimeout;
                            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType;
                            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddRange(Parameters.ToArray());
                            sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
                            sqlConnection.Open();
                            using (SqlDataReader dataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                            {
                                while (dataReader.Read())
                                {
                                    if (typeof(ResultType).BaseType == typeof(System.ValueType))
                                    {
                                        var sqlValue = dataReader.GetValue(0);
    
                                        if (sqlValue == DBNull.Value)
                                            list.Add(default);
                                        else
                                            list.Add((ResultType)ChangeType(sqlValue, typeof(ResultType)));
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        //handle complex types (objects)
                                        ResultType item = new ResultType();
                                        Type itemType = item.GetType();
                                        for (int columnNr = 0; columnNr < dataReader.FieldCount; columnNr++)
                                        {
                                            PropertyInfo prop = itemType.GetProperty(dataReader.GetName(columnNr));
    
                                            if (prop == null) continue;
    
                                            var value = dataReader.GetValue(columnNr);
                                            if (value == null || value == DBNull.Value)
                                            {
                                                prop.SetValue(item, null);
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                prop.SetValue(item, value);
                                            }
                                        }
                                        list.Add(item);
                                    }
                                }
                                sqlConnection.Close();
                            }
                            sqlCommand.Parameters.Clear();
                        }
                    }
                });
    
                return list;
            }
}
```

ReliableSqlCommand contains this as a property:

```
public List<SqlParameter> Parameters { get; } = new List<SqlParameter>();
```

Comment: Could you use [SqlParameterColection.CopyTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.copyto?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)?

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your code, I could imagine the following. (Note that I haven't tested it.)

You pass a function to `retryPolicy.Execute()`, which seems to correctly handle your database actions, disposing all connections, commands, datareaders, etc.

However, I assume that the `retryPolicy` can already start executing a new run of that function while a previous run is still active/running (or at least not yet fully completed). In that case, the parameters in `ReliableSqlCommand.Parameters` will be added to a new instance of `SqlCommand`, which is clearly not allowed when those parameters are still "alive" in a previous running function call in the background (which is still waiting for a database timeout exception, perhaps).

I do not see a straightforward stable/reliable fix for this.

Within the function, you could try to make new copies/instances of the `Parameter` objects and assign those copies to the `SqlCommand` instance. But in case you have output parameters, you will have to update the `ReliableSqlCommand.Parameters` collection afterwards. When having multiple running/overlapping function calls, that might be tricky as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is either to ensure the parameters are removed from the old command, or cache the command

If I understand correctly, the `Execute` function retries the lambda, and swallows any exceptions along the way. It does not execute multiple times concurrently.

Unfortunately, `SqlCommand.Dispose` does not remove the parameters from the command.

So option 1 is:

```cs
using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(CommandText, sqlConnection))
{
    try
    {
.......
    }
    finally
    {
        sqlCommand.Parameters.Clear();
    }
}
```

**A better option in my opinion, given that a parameter is supposed to be used with only one command, is to cache the command also.**

There is nothing wrong with this, as long as the connection is changed each time.

```cs
public ReliableSqlCommand 
{
    public SqlCommand Command { get; set; }
```

Then instead of `using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand...`, just use the existing `_command`:

```cs
_command.Connection = sqlConnection;
```

If you don't want to expose your command object directly, you could make a wrapper that adds and deletes the parameters.

It's not strictly necessary to dispose `SqlCommand`, because it's `Dispose` does nothing. But for consistency's sake, you may want to have `ReliableSqlCommand` be disposable as well.

Comment: I was thinking also on using a try catch/finally block. I will give it a try.